# Bootstrap cards not responsive and not breaking text?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-5

i'm coding a kanboard with drag\drop functionality to integrate it in a wordpress website.

So i wrote few functions to load an empty kanboard and, after an option select, populate it with some cards to drag and drop around.

Problem is : kanboard columns work perfectly, i can't say the same for the cards. Here is what i get :
[screen capture of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooXUI.png)

I left here the HTML\PHP code that generates both the empty kanboard and the cards, thank you.

Function for kanboard:

```
/////////////////// KANBAN OK
// Funzione per generare il contenuto HTML della kanban board
function display_kanban_board_first() {
global $wpdb;
$status_table = 'dbd_kan_status';
// Recupera i nomi delle colonne della kanban board dalla tabella degli stati
$status_query = "SELECT id, status_name FROM $status_table";
$statuses = $wpdb->get_results($status_query);
// Genera il markup HTML per la kanban board
ob_start();
?>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/6.4.2/tinymce.min.js" integrity="sha512-sWydClczl0KPyMWlARx1JaxJo2upoMYb9oh5IHwudGfICJ/8qaCyqhNTP5aa9Xx0aCRBwh71eZchgz0a4unoyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<style>
   #abslt {
   display: none;
   /* display: flex; */
   background: #ffaf00;
   width: 64.4%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   z-index:999;
   }
   .container-class {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   }
   .card-text-truncate {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div id="abslt">
      <div class="card create-new-task-card" id="create-new-task-card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Nuova Task</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="task-name">Task</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="task-name" id="task-name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="task-description">Descrizione</label>
               <textarea class="form-control" name="task-description" id="task-description" cols="70" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="task-status">Status</label>
               <select class="form-control" name="task-status" id="task-status">
                  <?php foreach ($statuses as $status) : ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($status->id); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($status->status_name); ?></option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" id="edit-button" onclick="editTask()">Modifica</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" id="save-button" onclick="saveTask()">Salva</button>
               <button class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel-button" onclick="createTask()">Annulla</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="kanban-heading">
      <strong class="kanban-heading-text">Kanban Board</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="task-button-block">
      <button id="task-button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createTask()">Crea Task</button>>
   </div>
   <div class="kanban-board">
      <div class="row flex-row flex-sm-nowrap py-3">
         <?php foreach ($statuses as $status) : ?>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
            <div class="card bg-light">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="kanban-block col-md-3 col-12" id="<?php echo esc_attr($status->status_name); ?>" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-status-id="<?php echo esc_attr($status->id); ?>" style="padding:5px; min-width:350px;">
                     <h4 class="mb-3"><?php echo esc_html($status->status_name); ?></h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- container fluid -->
<?php
return  ob_get_clean();
}
// Registra AJAX per le funzioni
add_action('wp_ajax_display_kanban_board_first', 'display_kanban_board_first');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_display_kanban_board_first', 'display_kanban_board_first');
```

Function to retrieve the cards:

```
function display_kanban_board_ajax() {
  if (isset($_POST['option_value'])) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $option_value = $_POST['option_value'];

    // JSON 
    $response_data = array();

    global $wpdb;
    $kanban_table = 'dbd_kan_task';

    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
      "
      SELECT task.id, task.status_id, task.id_cliente, task.id_utente, task.title, task.description
      FROM $kanban_table AS task
      WHERE task.id_utente = %d
        AND task.id_cliente = %s
     
      ",
      $user_id,
      $option_value
    );
    $tasks = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
      $response_data[] = array(
        'html_content' => '
          <div class="card mb-3 mon" id="'.esc_attr($task->title).'" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" data-task-id="'.esc_attr($task->id).'" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">'.esc_html($task->title).'</h5>
              <p class="card-text card-text-truncate">'.esc_html($task->description).'</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary task-modal-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#task-modal" data-task-title="'.esc_attr($task->title).'" data-task-description="'.esc_attr($task->description).'">Open Modal</button>
            </div>
          </div>',
        'status_id' => $task->status_id
      );
    }

    wp_send_json_success($response_data);
  } else {
    wp_send_json_error('option_value non è stato ricevuto');
  }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_display_kanban_board_ajax', 'display_kanban_board_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_display_kanban_board_ajax', 'display_kanban_board_ajax');
```

I'd like to see cards correctly nested into each column, with the text on newline if needed. Thanks for your help.

I tried editing CSS, Classes and take a look to the Bootstrap documentation, without success. Honestly i don't get why it didn't work.